# Angular router calls canActivate of element 1 even if router navigates to unguarded element 2

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have two components : `HomeComponent` which is guarded by AuthGuard, and `LoginComponent`which doesn't have any guard on it.

When I call `logout()` from `HomeComponent`, I destroy the token from `localStorage` and call `this.router.navigate(['/login'])`. This redirects me to `LoginComponent` just for a split second; and then my application acts as if I tried to call `HomeComponent` directly and thereby calling the `canActivate()` function again, which leads to full reload of the application.

Here are portions of my code:

Logout function

```
   logout() {
        // remove user from local storage to log user out
        localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        this.currentUserSubject.next(null);
    }
```

`app.routing.ts`

```
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
```

My AuthGuard's `canActivate()`

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        const currentUser = this.authenticationService.currentUserValue;
        if (currentUser) {
            // authorised so return true
            return true;
        }

        // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
        this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url }});
        return false;
    }
```

I expect that the application doesn't get reloaded and it just goes to `/login`. How can I achieve this?

**EDIT 1**
I tried creating a mini version of my app in stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stack-overflow-error-sample). I am a newbie to Angular, hence I had little problem recreating the issue there.
After clicking the login button in the demo,a localStorage item is created but router is not navigating to `/`. I request you to kindly remove the `/login...` part from browser URL and hit enter to reload the page. You will the see how the app behaves.
Try logging out and see the issue.

Comment: The behavior is caused by some other code that you haven't posted. My guess is that somewhere, you navigate to the home component when the current user becomes null. If you want us to find where the problem is, post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem, as a stackblitz.

Comment: I have recreated a small version of it in stackblitz. Please check it once. Link edited in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reloading happens because you're using

```
<a href="" ...>
```

to logout. This tells the browser to navigate to the current URL (i.e. reload the page).

You should use a button, and not a link. If you use a link, at least prevent the default action of the link:

```
(click)="logout($event)"

logout(event: Event) {
    // ...
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stack-overflow-error-sample-9mipey?file=src%2Fapp%2Fui%2Fheader%2Fheader.component.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot man! I wasted many hours just for a simple mistake. ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have a subscriber to `this.currentUserSubject.next(null);` which loads your `HomePage`. This of course directs to `/login`. A solution would be to check for the `null` in the subscriber.

Comment: I checked that in my `HeaderComponent` (refer to edit above). I tried checking if it was null before doing anything. But the app still shows the same behaviour. I request you to kindly check the stackblitz sample.